# How to improve this C# code to count holes in numbers?

Tags: c#

I want to solve this puzzle with a more elegant code in C#.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int numero = 12345678;
        int check = CountHoles(numero);
        Console.WriteLine(check);   
    }

    public static int CountHoles(int num){
        int roles = 0;
        for (int i=0; i < num.ToString().Length; i++ ){
            string ver = "";                
            ver = num.ToString().Substring(i,1);                
            if (ver.Contains("0") || ver.Contains("4") || ver.Contains("6") || ver.Contains("9")){
                roles++;
            }               
            if (ver.Contains("8")){
                roles = roles+2;
            }
        }       
        return roles;       
    }
}
```

.Net Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/3s8ucy

Thanks :)

Comment: I recommend you to visit [this](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site instead. as it is dedicated to improvement on existing, working, code.

Comment: Thanks :D I didn't know this one.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for a code review. It's probably more suited to [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like to use dictionary maps in place of if-statements. You can use LINQ to get an array of digits from the string and then another LINQ statement to sum the results (or you can combine the two into a single LINQ statement).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    private static Dictionary<int, int> _holeMap = new Dictionary<int, int>
    {
        { 0, 1 },
        { 1, 0 },
        { 2, 0 },
        { 3, 0 },
        { 4, 1 },
        { 5, 0 },
        { 6, 1 },
        { 7, 0 },
        { 8, 2 },
        { 9, 1 }                
    };

    public static void Main()
    {
        int numero = 12345678;
        int check = CountHoles(numero);
        Console.WriteLine(check);   
    }

    public static int CountHoles(int num){
        var digits = num
            .ToString()
            .Select(c => int.Parse(c.ToString()));

        return digits.Sum(d => _holeMap[d]);
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/gI5f02

Comment: I like the idea of using dictionary. It's a very good answer, but in this particular case I can't use another dependency, sorry I forgot to mention it before, it's my first question here.

Comment: @Emerson You can just use an array in this case. `var _holeMap = new int[] { 1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,2,1 }`.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to convert the number to string, you can improve method `CountHoles` like this:

```
int holes = 0;
do{
        float tmp = (float) num / 10;    
        num /= 10;
        int ver = (tmp - num) * 10;

        if (ver == 0 || ver == 4 || ver == 6 || ver == 9)    holes++;             
        if (ver == 8)  holes += 2;

    }while (num != 0)       
    return roles;
```

Comment: I didn't get the idea of using float and tmp. Why?

Comment: @Emerson, if `num = 123` then `tmp` will be `12.3` and `num/10 = 12` .. then `(tmp - num) * 10 = (12.3 - 12) * 10 = 0.3 * 10 = 3` .. I used this way to separate the number.